# Create BigQuerl ML Model using Google api (Java)

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Using a Java Utility , I need to create a BQML Model using an existing BQ table input data for evaluation.

Is there a way to create Models using the REST api.
Also  executing a CREATE MODEL sql ,  gives allowLargeResults error and unable to set that via api as it requires a destination table.

CREATE or Replace MODEL <DATASETNAME.ModelName> OPTIONS (model_type='logistic_reg', input_label_cols=['level_flag'], DATA_SPLIT_METHOD ='NO_SPLIT', AUTO_CLASS_WEIGHTS = TRUE) AS SELECT features,level_flag FROM <DATASETNAME.TABLENAME>

Comment: Could you share your CREATE MODEL query and configurations and what exact error message you've got? I believe sending a query is the right way.

Comment: @YunZhang It works fine from BQ UI . However gives error when I execute it from the java API.

Comment: Please edit your question and put query and error message in it.